# CI pipeline in GitLab

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I am new to GITLAB. I have created a repository and pushed my code to the repository.
I am trying to create pipeline to build the project.
Help me to create the correct yml file to build the pipeline.

```yaml
default:
  tags:
    - windows

stages:
  - build


build_job:
  stage: build
  script:
  - 'echo building...'
  - $msbuild = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
  - '&$msbuild WebApplication1.sln'
```

```
Error
& : The term 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe' is not 
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if 
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:262 char:2
+ &$msbuild WebApplication1.sln
+  ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program File...Bin\MSBuild.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:02
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Comment: Does the path and exe actually exist inside the runner?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that executable based on your path exists and try this code instead:

```yaml
stages:
  - build

variables:
  MSBUILD_PATH: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe'

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - '& "$env:MSBUILD_PATH" WebApplication1.sln'
```